# How can I confirm my new notebook battery is genuine?

Tags: laptop, battery

I have just purchased a replacement for HP DV6 Pavilion laptop battery from a local store in my country.

I am not sure that the battery is genuine. How can I check and confirm that the battery is genuine?

I'm using Windows Vista.

Comment: I would take several good-quality photos and post them here. Use a proper digital camera if you have one, good bright light helps. make sure any labels are legible, take close-ups if your lens will focus close enough.

Comment: My old IBM Thinkpad battery utility would indicate if the battery was not genuine. The HP Battery Check utility may do the same.